# Pandas - How to group sequences

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How to group a pandas (or dask) dataframe and get the min, max and some operation, only when the diference between the grouped rows are 1 second?

**MY DATA:**

| ID | DT | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:01:00 | 7 |
| 1 | 12:01:01 | 1 |
| 1 | 12:01:02 | 4 |
| 1 | 12:01:03 | 3 |
| 1 | 12:01:08 | 1 |
| 1 | 12:01:09 | 5 |
| 2 | 12:01:09 | 6 |
| 1 | 12:01:10 | 6 |
| 1 | 12:01:11 | 4 |

**RETURN:**

| ID | MENOR_DT | MAIOR_DT | SOMA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:01:00 | 12:01:03 | 15 |
| 1 | 12:01:08 | 12:01:11 | 16 |
| 2 | 12:01:09 | 12:01:09 | 6 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["DT"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["DT"])

tmp = df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False)["DT"].apply(
    lambda x: (x.diff().bfill() != "1 second").cumsum()
)

df = (
    df.groupby(["ID", tmp])
    .agg(
        ID=("ID", "first"),
        MENOR_DT=("DT", "min"),
        MAIOR_DT=("DT", "max"),
        SOME=("VALOR", "sum"),
    )
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
df["MENOR_DT"] = df["MENOR_DT"].astype(str).str.split().str[-1]
df["MAIOR_DT"] = df["MAIOR_DT"].astype(str).str.split().str[-1]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  MENOR_DT  MAIOR_DT  SOME
0   1  12:01:00  12:01:03    15
1   1  12:01:08  12:01:11    16
2   2  12:01:09  12:01:09     6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['seq'] = np.nan  # create a temp column

# sort the DF, find the seconds difference, and update the seq columns
# ffill to group all rows that has a 1 second or less of difference

df['seq']=(df.sort_values(['ID','DT'])   
           .assign(seq=df['seq']
                   .mask(pd.to_timedelta(df['DT']).dt.total_seconds()
                         .diff().ne(1), 1))['seq']
           .cumsum()
           .ffill()
)

# groupby ID, seq and take the aggregate
# drop the seq columns

(df.groupby(['ID','seq']).agg(MENOR_DT= ('DT','min'), 
                              MAIOR_DT= ('DT','max'), 
                              SOMA = ('VALOR','sum'))
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns=['seq']))
```

```
    ID  MENOR_DT    MAIOR_DT    SOMA
0   1   12:01:00    12:01:03    15
1   1   12:01:08    12:01:11    16
2   2   12:01:09    12:01:09    6
```